# Usage of the particle "ли"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Do I still have to use the particle "ли" if I already have "или"?

For example,

Он не сказал, будет ли он есть или нет.
Vs.
Он не сказал, будет он есть или нет.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, this is considered as superfluous, so the second («Он не сказал, будет он есть или нет») will do. However, if you don't have the «или нет» part, the «ли» is to be used:

> Он не сказал, будет ли он есть.

Comment: While formally indeed superfluous, it's quite common. You are fine either way!

Answer (score 0):

Your both examples is acceptable, however in `Он не сказал, будет ли он есть или нет.` `или нет` is redundant. `ли` is like `whether` which implies `or not`.